# Determine xcode command line tools version

Tags: command-line, xcode

How do I determine what version(s) of xcode command line tools I have?

I tried doing

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is the Apple LLVM version the same as the version of xcode command line tools?

Comment: +1. It was really hard to craft a Google search to find an answer to this. I searched `xcode command line tools installed version` but got a lot of irrelevant matches. Btw, did Dog G.'s answer work for you?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Finding the CLI version number depends on the combination of which particular OS and which particular CLI Tools are installed. One of these should work:

On versions 10.9 and later (OS X Yosemite to macOS Monterey):

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
```

on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion):

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI
```

Comment: If they ever change the pkg name again, running `pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i tools` should help locate it.

Comment: On macOS Catalina `com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables` is still a good package to use for this:

`pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
version: 11.3.0.0.1.1574140115`

Comment: @phatblat: Catalina 10.15.4, fm zsh CL: `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version` ==> `No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.`  Ideas??

Comment: @Seamus, sounds like you don't have the CLI tools installed. That's what I get on 10.15.4 when looking for the old package name: `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.` I'm on a fresh 10.15.4 install that I installed the CLI tools on first before installing Xcode 11.4.1: `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
version: 11.4.1.0.1.1586360307`

Comment: @phatblat: Thanks for the feedback, but the CL tools are definitely installed - wonder why Apple leaves this versioning business so poorly defined?... Oh scratch that - I think I know the answer :)

Comment: Where is the information retrieved?

Comment: Helpful for a short term fix, but where did this incantation come from?

Comment: Just a reminder, the info from pkgutil is only the recorded when run the .pkg installer. So, if you remove the dir `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` , the returned value is still the same.

Answer (score 18):

I had XCode Commandline Tools installed for sure, but not XCode itself.

None of the available answers to get the version worked. `pkgutil` didn't give me the package of the XCode Commandline Tools, with none of the suggested package names.

Not having XCode installed (and having no need for it), I could not look in settings dialogs of that either.

`xcode-select --version` only gave me the version of `xcode-select` itself, with no clue as to the commandline tools version.

`softwareupdate --list` told me everything was up to date.

However I knew that my version must be out of date as the installer for one of homebrew packages told me so!

How I finally found out what version of the XCode Commandline Tools is installed I stumbled upon the command:

```
softwareupdate --history
```

Which listed 12.3 as the last version it updated...

```
Display Name                                       Version    Date                  
------------                                       -------    ----                  
Safari                                             14.0       04/11/2020, 12:26:12  
Command Line Tools for Xcode                       12.1       04/11/2020, 22:38:33  
Safari                                             14.0.2     15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
Safari                                             14.0.1     15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
Command Line Tools for Xcode                       12.3       15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
macOS Big Sur                                      11.2.1     14/02/2021, 20:57:56  
macOS Big Sur 11.2.2                               11.2.2     08/03/2021, 09:02:20
```

So when you know for sure the commandline tools are installed (because, for instance, `xcode-select --install` tells you so) but none of the other methods works, check `softwareupdate --history`!

Comment: This is much more useful/reliable than Doc G.'s answer and its recyclers, since in this way you can get the required information without needing to know the arcana of packages, version-dependent names, etc.

Answer (score 13):

In terminal do

```
xcodebuild -version
```

Or, if you know the full path of xcodebuild, you can prepend that. In my case, I did

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```

example output:

```
Xcode 10.1
Build version 10B61
```

(adapted from https://www.garron.me/en/bits/what-xcode-version-am-i-running.html).

Comment: Using Mojave here. `xcodebuild -version` was what I was looking for.

Comment: This does not work if Xcode is not installed. If only the CommandLineTools are installed, this path does not exist.

Comment: But the question was for the command line tools - aren't they at different version numbers?

Comment: Doesn't exist in Big Sur

Comment: This only displays the Xcode version **not the Command Line tools version** - which can be different.

Answer (score 11):

For versions of macOS X 10.9 Mavericks and later, this code will provide you the version of both Xcode and Command Line Tools for Xcode, if either are installed:

```
# Xcode
if pkgutil --pkgs=com.apple.pkg.Xcode >/dev/null; then
    echo Xcode: $(pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.Xcode | awk '/version:/ {print $2}')
else
    echo Xcode: not installed
fi

# Command Line Tools for Xcode
if pkgutil --pkgs=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables >/dev/null; then
    echo CommandLineTools: $(pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | awk '/version:/ {print $2}')
else
    echo CommandLineTools: not installed
fi
```

Comment: You can use `pkgutil --pkgs=com.apple.pkg.Xcode > /dev/null` (and `pkgutil --pkgs=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables > /dev/null`) to avoid having to `grep` the result of `pkgutil --pkgs`.

Answer (score 6):

For modern versions of xcode the command `xcode-select --version` will display the version number of command line tools, whether or not Xcode.app is installed.

I'm answering against the more recent version (where the tools actually are in the Xcode.app pkg), but I'm pretty sure that if the path & output returned by `xcode-select -p`, `gcc -v`,  and `llvm-gcc -v/clang -v` are harmonious then they should be the same, i.e.

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix

$ llvm-gcc -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix

$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Note that llvm-gcc is a link to clang,

```
$ls -al /usr/bin/llvm-gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5 Oct 19  2014 /usr/bin/llvm-gcc -> clang
```

so the output of `llvm-gcc -v` and `clang -v` should be identical although that may or may not be the case for you (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708732/602581 for some more details)

Comment: The version that these tools output isn't necessarily the same as the Xcode command line tools version. Example, `clang --version` returns `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)`, while Doc G.'s `pkgutil` command returns `version: 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice way I've found to scriptify things,

```
BUILD_TOOL_PATH=$(xcode-select -p)

if [[ ${BUILD_TOOL_PATH} == "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" ]]; then
    BUILD_TOOL_VER=$(xcodebuild -version | /usr/bin/grep "Xcode" | sed -e 's/Xcode //' | cut -d. -f1)
elif [[ ${BUILD_TOOL_PATH} == "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools" ]]; then
    BUILD_TOOL_VER=$(pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | /usr/bin/grep "version" | sed -e 's/version: //' | cut -d. -f1)
else
    echo "Error: On macOS, either Xcode or the Command Line Tools must be installed!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Obviously, you can remove the `else`/error condition. If you need to do something for a specific version of Xcode/CLT (relevant to the time of this answer), you can for example,

```
if [[ ${BUILD_TOOL_VER} -ge 15 ]]; then
    export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-ld_classic"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
```

Works for Montery (OS 12.xx)

Comment: How deos this differ from other answers like https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181994/237

Comment: 1-Confirmed to work with newest version of MacOS 2-included grep to filter out extraneous information