# Disable Xcode Command Line Tools

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

I changed the Command Line Tools in Xcode settings, hoping it would solve an error with arm64e, but xcodebuild ended up taking over `make` command which makes the compiling process slower with my Theos project.

Xcode does not allow me to revert changes of Command Line Tools, is there other way to revert the change? I don't want xcodebuild to run when using `make`

[image]

I readed every solutions I found online but nothing helps, tried reinstalled Xcode, xcodebuild still present with `make` in Terminal

Comment: What exactly did you change, and how? And what do you mean by „xcodebuild still presemt in Terminal“?

Comment: I changed the Command Line Tools in Xcode settings but i want to revert to default, leaving it blank. Question edited

Comment: It’s entirely possible I’m not even answering your proper question. If you need help with debugging `make`, we would need a very detailed edit to have a [MCVE of your setup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or point you to Stack Overflow. I’ll answer how to reset any change made to the selection of command line tools in case your problem is directly related to the choices made in the shown GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Quit Xcode
- Open a Finder window showing your Xcode program
- Open a command line prompt (terminal.app is fine)
- Type `xcode-select --switch`
- Drag the Xcode program icon you want to be default into the command line window and release the icon
- Press enter

The select tool lets you have [multiple versions of the tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180957/5472) and switch back and forth or even [request an install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339015/5472) from Apple of the tools without having Xcode.app installed. If this process fails, your Xcode preferences are corrupted, so you’d uninstall the app or make a new user profile to validate whether the app preferences or user preferences need to be trashed or fixed.

Comment: Switching to Xcode didn't helped, as it was already set according to `gcc --version`. After some more research, I figured my command line tools was `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. I switched to that instead, and it did got rid of xcodebuild, compiling is fast again. The Command Line Tools is now blank in Xcode settings. Answer accepted