# How to know what is the latest acceptable version of Xcode for a specific OS X or macOS?

Tags: xcode, software-update, mac-appstore, upgrade, macports

I have OS X El Capitan. I want to install MacPorts. According to its page it needs Xcode.

According to this post: [Determine xcode command line tools version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181994/348694)

to know the Xcode version the following command should be used:

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
```

The command works and returns:

```
version: 8.2.0.0.1.1480973914
```

Now, the reason for this post, I want to have the latest acceptable version of Xcode for El Capitan for it to work fine with MacPorts

According with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server#comment52050763_19908327) at [Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server), it does mention to use the Command Line Tools as search criteria at the URL https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (btw that URL redirects to https://developer.apple.com/download/all).

With the suggested *search criteria* appears as result many Xcode versions

**Question**

How to know what is the latest acceptable version of Xcode for a specific OS X or macOS?

Therefore, is there an official table indicating or showing all versions of Xcode that can be installed for each OS X and macOS release?

So, once known the latest acceptable version to update Xcode in OS X for El Capitan - I am assuming that in https://developer.apple.com/download/all is possible to download in peace the specific .dmg file, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not official, there is [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com).

For OS X El Capitan, the answer would be Xcode 8.2.1. Next would be Xcode 8.3 which requires macOS Sierra. Once you have this information, one can easily verify by comparing a search for [Xcode 8.2](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%20OS%20X%208.2) with [Xcode 8.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%20OS%20X%208.3).

> Note: Some links given in this answer require being able to sign to Apple Developer.

Comment: Thanks - because I have `10.11.6` the best latest acceptable version is `Xcode 8.2.1` - huge thanks for the support!